# Filter for the list of numbers in slick 3

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I came across a condition that to filter for the list of numbers in slick-3. Here is my entity.

```
    case class Company(id:Long, name: String, companyTypeId: Option[List[Long]] = None)

    implicit def GetResultCompany(implicit e0: GR[Long], e1: GR[String], e2: GR[Option[List[Long]]]): GR[Company] = GR{
        prs => import prs._
          CompanyTest.tupled((<<[Long], <<[String],<<?[List[Long]]))
      }
    class CompanyTable(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[Company](_tableTag, Some("base"), "Company") {
        def * = (id, name,companyTypeId) <> (CompanyTest.tupled, CompanyTest.unapply)
        def ? = (Rep.Some(id), Rep.Some(name), companyTypeId).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=> CompanyTest.tupled((_1.get, _2.get _3)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))
        val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("CompanyId", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
        val name: Rep[String] = column[String]("Name", O.Length(250,varying=true))
        val companyTypeId: Rep[Option[List[Long]]] = column[Option[List[Long]]]("CompanyTypeId", O.Length(19,varying=false), O.Default(None))
      }
    lazy val companyTable = new TableQuery(tag => new CompanyTable(tag))
```

Here i want to search for `companyTypeId` and it is `Option[List[Long]]`

I tried doing by `companyTable.filter(_.companyTypeId === Some(List(1,2)))` but getting `Vector()` and the table is having a row of data with companyTypeId as {1}.I am using Postgres DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the entity look in the database? Do you really store a list of values in one column?

Comment: @Gregor Raýman... yes it looks like{1,2,3} and the Data Type is bigint[]

Comment: Interesting. I assume normalising it a another linked table is not an option for you. I am not sure how the built in support of Slick for Array columns is, but this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/v7lhyCd8_6k) could be helpful.

Comment: @Gregor Raýman... I am not supposed to normalize it by another table. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Gregor Raýman....I didnt find the way to do this :-( So opting for a linked table.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try it this way :

```
companyTable.filter(_.companyTypeId inSet(Traversable(List(1,2)))) 
// the above query filters rows with values in the given list
```

Comment: @bhavya.....i am getting Type Mismatch error like expected: Traversable[List[Long]], actual:Traversable[Long]

Comment: @bhavya...this is same as i tried as in the question. If the db has the ids {1,2} and i am giving a search like companyTable.filter(_.companyTypeId inSet(Traversable(List(1,2))))  will fetch the result. But in case of I send companyTable.filter(_.companyTypeId inSet(Traversable(List(1)))) will not yield any result.

Comment: @Jet .. is it failing only for single valued list ?? like List(1) .. List(2) ... or even all other cases ?

Comment: @bhavya...It will yield the result only if I give the values as it is in db, fails for rest all cases

Comment: @Jet Ya I get that .. I never got to work on Postgres , can u just paste me the query written at the db end for this case  , so that I can suggest if we can build the query using any of the slick's method

Comment: @Bhavya...i was trying in Postgres to find the result for my question, but i didnt get: -(. Select * from base."CompanyTest" where "CompanyTypeId" = '{1}' is not yielding any result even though the db got the values {1,2}. But i am able to get the result for Select * from base."CompanyTest" where "CompanyTypeId" = '{1,2}'.

Comment: @Jet .. oh so mabbe you should now find out some other way of storing and fetching values for this scenario.